# Jenkins + Maven Manual Installation

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, jenkins-plugins, maven-3

I installed Jenkins on to 2 new machines no-problemo!

But, when attempting to integrate Maven, I am having "command not found" in my Jenkins log, yet I can run `mvn` no problem in the command line.

So, I thought it was a PATH issue - so I added the /bin and also the / (of the location where Maven is extracted to), yet I'm still getting the error.

I tried adding the PATH to my ~/.bash_profile as well, so my current PATH is:

`$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/Users/jenkins/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/Users/jenkins/apache-maven-3.5.2`

Still, Jenkins will not find Maven. I do NOT want to globally install Maven, as it may affect the other 5 build servers we have that are working with Maven correctly (not sure how it's working).

Comment: Configure Maven into the global tools configuration of Jenkins and usually you should let Jenkins install it by installer...

Comment: Depending on how Jenkins is started .bash_profile may not have been read.  Jenkins can handle a private copy of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by simply re-connecting the Jenkins Slave. Thanks for your feedback!